# Chicago Manual of Style (Author-Date) in-text citation help for quoting a politician speaking in a House of Commons Debate

Tags: citations

The general in-text citation rule is this (for a quotation): (Last name Year, Page Number). In 13.65 (17th Edition), CMoS gives an example of a detailed in-text citation:

> 1. ... text in the quote here (Stephen W. Hawking, *A Brief History of Time: From the Big Bang to Black Holes* [New York: Bantam Books, 1988], 112).

Here is one for a detailed block quote (which is indented) from 13.70:

> 2. ... text in the quote here. (Gifford Pinchot, *To the South Seas* [Philadelphia: John Winston, 1930], 123)

CMoS does not say anything about the format of the in-text citation in these cases.

The format here seems like this: (Full name, Book Title [Publication area: Publisher, Year], Page number). Is this how it is supposed to be formatted or did CMoS just put them in a random order?

---

**Question:**
I am quoting a number of politicians speaking at the House of Commons. And I am told to provide a detailed citation for a block quote. The guide says nothing about this.

Here is what I have:

> ... text in the quote here. (Full Name [Windsor–Tecumseh, NDP, House of Commons Debates, Feb 25, 2016,] 1383–4)

Windsor–Tecumseh means "Member of the Canadian Parliament for the federal electoral district of Windsor–Tecumseh". NDP is the name of the political party.

Based on the formats of 1 and 2, I won't be able to give the required information: federal electoral district and name of political party. I also won't be able to give the month, which is important.

What is the right way to cite this?

Comment: Given that you use the author-date style, the examples in 13.65 of CMoS may not apply to you. The last part of 13.64 says "The advice in this section on placement relative to surrounding text is intended to supplement the system of notes and bibliography cov­ered in chapter 14. For author-date references, see chapter 15."

Section 15.26 deals with direct quotations in author-date style.

Comment: @jnanin Thanks for the comment. 15.26 does not however give me anything to go on with the rest of the details (e.g., name of political party). I am willing to go with any format that can be seen as standard. The block quote I am giving is a special case and it is not a must to strictly follow CMoS. I would prefer to, though. I want to know what others would do in this situation. How would you format the citation?

Comment: I am far from experienced as this is not something I usually cite, but legal materials (broadly construed) tend to have very different standard citation format. (See CMoS 14.276 onwards, for example.) My first guess is that these parliamentary speeches are public records and you cite the identifier for those records. Is this helpful to you?: https://library.carleton.ca/sites/default/files/help/writing-citing/Using_uniform_legal_citation_2018.pdf

Comment: @jnanin Yes, your last comment was helpful, both the links. Thanks. Turns out there isn't a perfect way to do this. I have to supplement the Author-Date style with notes in this case. I have looked at a few examples - I am going to change a few things and stick to it consistently. I guess that's what matters - consistency and detailed citation for my reader.

Comment: If you have an account with CMOS Online, there is a specific entry dealing with citing from Hansard, where everything said in the House of Commons is officially recorded: https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch14/ch14_sec313.html. I don't have an account, but I expect you will find your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest rising the question right at the source.  The webpage about The Parliament's Hansard, for example in English [here](https://www.ourcommons.ca/DocumentViewer/en/house/latest/hansard), includes the following invite:

> If you have any questions or comments regarding the accessibility of
>   this publication, please contact us at accessible@parl.gc.ca.

The use of the Bulletin as a reference for a scientific publication may well fall into the category «accessibility».  Equally, the library of The Parliament states [here](https://lop.parl.ca/sites/PublicWebsite/default/en_CA/ContactUs) multiple avenues to be contacted, e.g. by e-mail via info@parl.gc.ca.